# Count of Dates Based on the End of The Month

Tags: sql, count

I have a Table of Employee with DOJ and want to create another table with query which will contains the Distinct of DOJ and cumulative count of the Date

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
CAST(A.DOJ AS datetime) AS 'Work Date',
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(A.DOJ AS datetime)<=CAST(EOMONTH(A.DOJ) AS datetime) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Actual'
FROM BiMob..ManpowerGrossCKDL A
GROUP BY CAST(A.DOJ AS datetime)

Employee Code   DOJ            Date        Count
1        10/24/2019         10/24/2019  3
2        10/24/2019         10/25/2019  5
3        10/24/2019         10/26/2019  6
4        10/25/2019         
5        10/25/2019             
6        10/26/2019
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArQc7.png)

Comment: Your desired output has nothing to do with *the End of The Month*.

Comment: Yeah i might be wrong about the approach but can you show your perspective to achieve the final output. That will be great @forpas

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you want and why this output is expected.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your valuable effort :P @forpas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum function, using window functions:

```
SELECT A.DOJ AS WorkDate,
       COUNT(*) as count_on_date,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(A.DOJ AS date)) as count_cumulative
FROM BiMob..ManpowerGrossCKDL A
GROUP BY A.DOJ
ORDER BY WorkDate;
```

Notes:

1. I removed the `CAST()` on DOJ.  It already seems to represent a date and I see no reason to convert it to a `datetime`.
2. Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  They will just lead to confusion.  The best approach is to use names that don't require quotes.
3. I included an `ORDER BY` because you presumably want the results in date order.